# Azure function using Powershell to consume the data from an Event hub and POST the same to a REST API

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I want to create a Azure function using Powershell which will read data from the Azure Event Hub. Azure function has a template to get the data from the Azure Event hub and but I don't know how to post the same data to a REST API hosted on on-prem.
I have already created a hybrid connection for the on-prem connectivity.
I am new to Powershell development hence seeking your help.
Also, it would be a great help if someone can suggest any blog(s) to get more details on azure function development standard practice using Powershell.

Following is the code snippet that I want to update.

***run.ps1***

```
param($eventHubMessages, $TriggerMetadata)

Write-Host "PowerShell eventhub trigger function called for message array: $eventHubMessages"

$eventHubMessages | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "Processed message: $_" }
```

***host.json***

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "managedDependency": {
    "Enabled": true
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

***function.json***

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "eventHubMessages",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "pwo-events",
      "connection": "eventhub-reciever-policy",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you know that stream analytics does this natively, no code required

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid my ultimate goal is to post the data to REST API, that resides on-premise. I didn't mentioned this in the post.

Comment: I suggest you edit and post the entire requirement. Do you want to post to blob _and_ an on-premise REST API? If you have a high volume of data you might run out of storage on-premises

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid updated the question.

Comment: Have you investigated stream analytics?It might also be able to post to a on-prem REST API. I keep going on about it because streaming is not a trivial thing, you need to do things like manage queues and high water marks, and stream analytics does this automatically.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'll not receive the streaming data but I have been asked to use the Azure functions. Does stream analytics could suffice my requirement ??

Comment: Event hubs is streaming data. Not sure if it will fulfill you’re requirements but it is what inwould investigate first.

Answer (score 0):

To access to the object from the code in powershell script, the name of the bindings in the function.json file must be added in param section of the script.

```
# Input bindings passed via param 

param([byte[]] $Trigger, [String[]] $InputBlob, $TriggerMetadata) 


# Output passed via Push-OutputBinding 

Push-OutputBinding -name OutputBlob -value $SomeValue
```

Flow Structure:

[image]

Also, we have a blog which covers the info about eventhub telemetry with [Powershell](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6294/azure-event-hub-service-telemetry-example-with-powershell/).